# Función de suavizamiento

Tags: python

amigos, actualmente tengo un problema con mi trabajo de Python ya que por más que lo he intentado no he podido crear una función de suavizamiento para hallar luego un h óptimo.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd
```

Luego de esto genero unos datos aleatorios de la siguiente manera:

```
def f(x):
z = 2 + x**0.2*np.cos(10*x)/(x**(1/10))
    return(z)
plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
plt.plot(np.arange(0,2,0.01), f(np.arange(0,2,0.01)))
plt.title('Función evaluada entre 0 y 2')

n = 400
sigma = 0.6
np.random.seed(20210320) 
x = np.random.uniform(0, 2, n)
x = np.sort(x)
y = np.array([])
for ii in range(n):
y = np.append(y, f(x[ii]) + np.random.normal(0, sigma, 1))
```

Y finalmente realizo un gráfico de estos datos:

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.title('Función evaluada entre 0 y 2')
```

Pero mi problema radica en generar una función de suavizamiento que se las pondré en la siguiente imagen pero realmente no he sabido cómo formularla, agradecería demasiado si me pueden ayudar, por favor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito una urgente ayuda con esto.

Muchas gracias, amigos.